# how to access a private member function? when it is a boolean?

Tags: c++, private-members

how to access a private member function? when it is a boolean?

this is my code:

```
    class IntQueue
    {
    private:   
        bool isEmpty();         //private member function bool
        bool isFull();          //private member function bool
    public:
        bool isful();          //access isEmpty
        bool isemp();          //access isFull
    
    };
```

I was told to make the function isEmpty and isFull to a Private member function.

```
    //private function

    bool IntQueue::isEmpty()
    {
        bool status;
    
        if (numItems)
            status = false;
        else
            status = true;
    
        return status;
    }
    
    //private function

    bool IntQueue::isFull()
    {
        bool status;
    
        if (numItems < queueSize)
            status = false;
        else
            status = true;
    
        return status;
    }
```

is this a correct way of accessing a private function?

```
    //ACCESS THE PRIVATE MEMBER FUNCTION
    
    bool IntQueue::isemp()
    {
        isEmpty();
    }
    
    bool IntQueue::isful()
    {
        isFull();
    }
```

Comment: The usage in `isemp()` should RETURN the value returned by `isEmpty()`.   As in `bool IntQueue::isemp() {return isEmpty();}`.   Leaving out the `return` keyword means the function "falls off the end", and causes undefined behaviour - it doesn't magically cause the value returned by `IsEmpty()` to be returned to the caller.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question at all, but... Why would you give your public API mangled abbreviations, and your private/internal API proper full names?

Comment: how about if you want to use isEmpty() again to another method, can you automatically access isemp() or call isEmpty() again and return it? like this: void IntQueue::dequeue(int &num)
{
    if (isemp())
        cout << "The queue is empty.\n";
    else
    {
        // Move front
        front = (front + 1) % queueSize;
        // Retrieve the front item
        num = queueArray[front];
        // Update item count
        numItems--;
    }

}

Comment: @Peter Well actually, such code will probably "work" in non-optimized builds. The inner call to `isEmpty()` will place the empty boolean into return register (R0, EAX, whatever). And the outer `isemp()` will just jump back after, without writing something to the return register, so _appearing_ to return something valid. In optimized build, the compiler might inline the `isEmpty` call without writing to return register, and code suddenly stops working. Welcome to UB.

Comment: @prapin - Well, that's not true.   All of your arguments about placing results in return registers are specific to some implementations, and mean absolutely nothing for other implementations.    Don't make the mistake of assuming that, given code with undefined behaviour, the behaviour of your compiler in a non-optimised build is representative of other compilers in a non-optimised build.

Comment: @parpin To add a word of caution for everybody: Reasoning about what a compiled program *might* do in a particular case of UB can be an interesting intellectual excercise. But concluding that a case of UB is harmless based on such an excercise is *never* valid.

Answer (score 2):

No because there are not `return` statement in C++ non-void functions. This invokes *undefined behavior*. You have to return what `isEmpty()` and `isFull()` returns.

```
    //ACCESS THE PRIVATE MEMBER FUNCTION
    
    bool IntQueue::isemp()
    {
        return isEmpty();
    }
    
    bool IntQueue::isful()
    {
        return isFull();
    }
```

Comment: how about if you want to use isEmpty() again to another method, can you automatically access isemp() or call isEmpty() again and return it? like this: void IntQueue::dequeue(int &num)
{
 if (isemp())
  cout << "The queue is empty.\n";
 else
 {
  // Move front
  front = (front + 1) % queueSize;
  // Retrieve the front item
  num = queueArray[front];
  // Update item count
  numItems--;
 }
}

Comment: void IntQueue::dequeue(int &num)
{
 if (isEmpty())
  cout << "The queue is empty.\n";
 else
 {
  // Move front
  front = (front + 1) % queueSize;
  // Retrieve the front item
  num = queueArray[front];
  // Update item count
  numItems--;
 }
}

Answer (score -1):

how about if you want to use isEmpty() again to another method, can you automatically access isemp() or call isEmpty() again and return it?

like this

```
void IntQueue::dequeue(int &num)
{
    if (isemp())
        cout << "The queue is empty.\n";
    else
    {
        // Move front
        front = (front + 1) % queueSize;
        // Retrieve the front item
        num = queueArray[front];
        // Update item count
        numItems--;
    }
}
```

or this:

```
void IntQueue::dequeue(int &num)
{
    if (isEmpty())
        cout << "The queue is empty.\n";
    else
    {
        // Move front
        front = (front + 1) % queueSize;
        // Retrieve the front item
        num = queueArray[front];
        // Update item count
        numItems--;
    }
return isEmpty();
}
```